# Java Card - install applet

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

i´m trying to install an applet on my card but can´t find out how to. Is there someone who can help me may be a tutorial or so.

I tried `JCManager` to install and `JSmartCardExplorer` to start it
but it doesn´t work for me.

Comment: "it doesn´t work for me" - what does it mean? Could you please add some details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Card OS Specialty Community has an up to date Applet Tutorial that should prove useful to you:
http://www.javacardos.com/javacardforum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=114

Their forums should prove very useful to you.

Java Card is a subset of Java with language features similar to Java 1.3 and byte code similar to Java 2.0 (aka Java 1.2).

The Wikipedia article on Java Card has some additional resources as well:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Card

Your experience may vary depending on the Java Card model and vendor, but the Speciality Community forums should be able to help wirh those details.

Comment: I'm not sure about this... The first links website seems to be more of an online shop. I don't think it is agreeable with the SO rules. Moreover the javacard section of SO is pretty active.

Comment: @PaulBastian it's a very weirdly formatted site.  The tutorial is way down that page.

Comment: @PaulBastian I totally agree, Paul. Moreover, I think this answer does not answer OP's question (although he accepted it) - he asks for a tutorial for installing applet, not implementing.

Comment: @vojta my reasoning was that the OP could figure out the install mechanics from that tutorial.  Is that a bad approach?

Comment: I'd be happy for a member of the Java Card crowd to provide an answer.  I'll even encourage the OP to accept it instead if that happens and it's a quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you chose to go for Global Platform Pro, which is a very good tool for your task. So I would advise you to read the documentation from the Github page if you have questions about the usage:
[Here you go](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro#usage)

It covers all important parts, so here I will give you a general layout of what to do (independent from the tool you use):
1. Are you sure you have a JavaCard? Where did you buy it? Check all the documentation that came along with it. Because:
**First and most important:** you use a Card Manager that uses the Global Platform specification and before you can do anythingyou have to authenticate towards the Card Manager with the keys that were provided to you by your reseller or whoever. Cards often come with the default keys (0x40..0x4F) but some (e.g. Gemalto and G&D) have other preset keys. If you try to often to use them the card manager will lock itself and the card is bricked (this is kind of a brute-forceprotection).
If you figured this out you might want to know whats on the card,most tools have a command called `ls` for this.
Next you need an applet in an uploadable form, called a cap files.
Then you upload (some people say download, its a question of perspective) onto the card and afterwards you install/instantiate the applet.
In a productive environment you might now want to change the card manager keys or protect your card by any other mechanisms.
This information is only a minimum example, its important to read the documentation provided by your card vendor!!!
Good luck!